# How to enable Azure AD (azure active directory) Authentication in a Static website on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am hosting a static website through the $web container in the BLOB storage of an azure storage account and I need to place the static site with AD (Azure active directory) authentication but I don't know how those steps are done to place authentication

Comment: You'd need to implement authentication in your website with MSAL.js or you have to setup a Function app to act as a reverse proxy in front of your storage and setup AAD auth on that.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there isn't a toggle you can switch to get this behaviour. *But keep reading because there is a way to achieve an equivalent behaviour.*

It sounds like you are after something similar to what App Service (including Functions Apps) offer and is often referred to as EasyAuth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad.

AFAIK, an equivalent functionality doesn't exist for Blob storage. It is a passive service and will not do any authentication for you. It doesn't have implicit flow enabled. That means it will accept the OAuth tokens you provide, but it will not allow users to authenticate directly against it.

Assuming this is a Single Page Application, and that you don't want to protect the static files (.html, .js, .css, etc.) but only some data that exists either as blobs or sit behind APIs hosted somewhere else, protected by AAD, one way to achieve this is to create two containers:

1. The $web container that gets created when "Static website" is enabled
2. A "data" container, with "Access Level=Private (no anonymous access)"

Once those containers are in place, proceed to assign any permissions to the "data" container, or even to each individual blob in that container, using [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad#assign-rbac-roles-for-access-rights).

The final step is to use [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) in your Single Page Application hosted in the $web container to obtain the tokens necessary to access your blobs. Explaining how to do that would make this answer too long, but it's well covered in the MSAL.js documentation.